# How to find a particular object from an NSMutableArray iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, object, nsmutablearray

I have store many values in `NSMutableArray` like `@"New"`, `@"Old"`, `@"Future"`.  The `NSMutablArray` having 100+ objects. I need to find the `@"New"` objects from the array. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will do the trick most economically [tested]:

```
[myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate
   predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@", @"New"]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Gopinath if you have added constant string like `@"New"` then

```
int index = [array indexOfObject:@"New"];
```

will do the trick as

```
NSString *str1 = @"New";
NSString *str2 = @"New";
```

Then `str1` and `str2` points to same object.

And if you know the string that you are searching then is there any need of finding it?
Mundi's answer is also good.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do a fast enumeration of the objects?

```
NSMutableArray *matchingObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"New", @"Old", @"Future", nil];
NSInteger count = 0;
for (NSString *string in objects) {
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"New"]) {
        [matchingObjects addObject:string];
    }
    count++;
}
```

This way `matchingObjects` contains all of the objects that matched the test, and you can use `count` to get the index of all the matches.

Comment: good ans, u can filter object also by [string containsString: ] method

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to filter the array using a predicate block

```
[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary * bindings){
    [evaluatedObject isEqual:anObject];
}]];
```